# Private Key sign data in Java to PHP

Tags: java, php, private-key

I have to write PHP program to do the same function with the java sign function as follow

```
public static String sign(byte[] data, String privateKey) throws Exception {
          MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
          messageDigest.update(data);
          byte[] hashData = messageDigest.digest();
          
          StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
          
          byte[] keyBytes = Base64Utils.decode(privateKey.getBytes()); 
          PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);

          KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
          PrivateKey privateK = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);
          Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("NONEWithRSA");
          signature.initSign(privateK);
          signature.update(hashData);
          byte[] sign = signature.sign();
          return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sign);
}
```

I have done some research on google and try to write the PHP code as follow

```
public function sign($data, $privateKeyString){

     $privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($privateKeyString);
     $hashData = hash("sha256",$data);
     openssl_sign($hashData, $signature, $privateKey);
     openssl_free_key($privateKey);
     return base64_encode($signature);

}
```

I try to pass the same key with the data let's say "Hello" to both function and testing
the hash data are map but the outcome signature are different

Is there anyone can spot what cause the return base64 signature are different between the java and php?

Comment: figure out a bit is that the main issue should be I cannot find the signature algorithm from PHP that can support NONEwithRSA in java, is there any one know whether there is any alternative to cater it?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function sign($data, $privateKeyString){

     $privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($privateKeyString);
     $hashData = openssl_digest("sha256",$data);
     openssl_private_encrypt($hashData, $signature, $privateKey);
     openssl_free_key($privateKey);
     return base64_encode($signature);

}
```

Finally fixing the problem by using openssl_digest "sha256" instead of passing sha256 hash value into the for private key encrytion, due to the hashing need to be convert into the hex string instead of the original value.